Gson Custom Deserializer For Nested JSON
I have the below JSON. I want to be able to store it in an instance of a Java class.  I think that I need a custom deserializer to do so.  I have working code that can create JsonObject of the top level 'response_object' JSON string and then I can walk down to get things like the files array.  My question is can I write a custom deserializer that starts at the top level, it gets passed the JsonObject of the response_object and returns an instance.
For example, this experimental code gets me down to the files array and I can get specific values.  From my reading, I think that I can create a class called something like ResponseObject that implements a deserializer that takes a JsonObject and basically walks it to set properties and/or create instances of the nested classes (which would also have to be defined and I think need their own deserializers).  Am I correct?
JsonObject robj = value.getAsJsonObject("response_object");
JsonArray uarray = robj.getAsJsonArray("updates");
for(int i1 = 0; i1 < uarray.size(); i1++) {
    JsonElement jel = uarray.get(i1);
    JsonObject jobj = jel.getAsJsonObject();
    String v = jobj.get("upgrades_to_version").getAsString();
    JsonArray files = jobj.getAsJsonArray("files");
    for (int ij = 0; ij < files.size(); ij++ ) {
        JsonElement fel = files.get(ij);
        JsonObject fobj = fel.getAsJsonObject();
        url = fobj.get("url").getAsString();
    }
}

"response_object" : {
   "asset_type" : "software",
   "asset_virtual_id" : "Instance_Cluster-0001",
   "category" : "Software",
   "connect_transaction_id" : "11223344_1714400505026_Event-000001",
   "efd_transaction_id" : "H17246155",
   "event_time" : "2024-09-25 21:43:42",
   "event_time_ms" : 1727300622750,
   "event_type" : "software_update",
   "group" : "foo",
   "instance" : "0123456789abcdef",
   "response_code" : 200,
   "response_size" : 997,
   "software_update_request" : {
      "asset_event_detail" : {
         "body" : {
            "action" : "Order SW",
            "component" : "compid_xx",
            "description" : "Orderfix",
            "efd_product" : "Log Collector",
            "operation" : "order_software",
            "request_type" : "specific_fix",
            "update_ids" : [
               "1.0.1.0-fix001"
            ]
         },
         "header" : {
            "event_id" : "11223344_1714400505026_SWupdate-000002",
            "event_time" : "2024-04-29 09:00:00",
            "event_time_ms" : 1714400505026,
            "event_type" : "software_update"
         }
      }
   },
   "times" : {
      "efd_delta" : "1.5 seconds",
      "efd_recv" : 1727300622749,
      "efd_send" : 1727300621292
   },
   "type" : "11223344",
   "updates" : [
      {
         "applies_to_version" : "v1.0.1.0",
         "description" : "This is the initial release",
         "files" : [
            {
               "description" : "Runnable Jar File",
               "descriptor" : "data/installable-unit.fix",
               "hash" : "AHcK2tBVoETIZcINUefJcLrZmNxFFMyFnjEj4dCcc+8=",
               "hashAlgorithm" : "SHA-256",
               "size" : 14787032,
               "url" : "https://example.com/runnable1.jar",
               "url_type" : "edge"
            },
            {
               "description" : "Runnable",
               "descriptor" : "some_description",
               "hash" : "foo",
               "hashAlgorithm" : "SHA-256",
               "size" : 14787032,
               "url" : "https://example.com/runnable2.jar",
               "url_type" : "edge"
            }

         ],
         "id" : "1.0.1.0-fix001",
         "name" : "Initial Release 001",
         "release_date" : "2024-04-25T18:42:00.382Z",
         "status" : "available",
         "type" : "fix pack",
         "upgrades_to_version" : "v1.0.1.0"
      }
   ]
}


Using nested classes and arrays within Gson has been well-described in other similar questions and answers. If you feel that your question is new or unique, please tell the details and explain why. Show what you've attempted  and the problems that you may have run into with your attempt.

And if you have your Java classes correctly made, complete with Gson annotations, then there is no need for a custom deserializer.

For example, this current JSON could be parsed into several Java classes including a ResponseWrapper class that held a Respose field: @SerializedName("response_object") private Response response; instance. The Response class could have an updates List<Update>field: @SerializedName("updates") private List<Update> updates;.

The Update class could then hold a List<FileB> files field (renamed from File to avoid confusing the compiler): @SerializedName("files") private List<FileB> files;. And the FileB class would hold fields for all the key attributes that you wanted to hold on to from the corresponding JSON object. You could then use getters and streams to extract all the FileB objects held within the JSON.

For example, List<FileB> files = responseWrapper.getResponse().getUpdates().stream().flatMap(update -> update.getFiles().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Thank you,  your comments helped.  I don't have the entire file as a class. I am not sure that I need it and as you suggested that is probably not practical.  For now I am able to get what I need to a class.  If I need the rest, I can do so.
